# Setters for Option members

Tags: scala, case-class

I am trying a coding exercise where the task is to delete a node from a Binary Search Tree. This is what I have currently:

```
sealed trait Node {
  val label: Int
}
case class LeafNode(override val label: Int) extends Node
case class BranchNode(override val label: Int, var left: Option[Node], var right: Option[Node]) extends Node


def deleteFromBST(root: Option[Node], valueToDelete: Int): Option[Node] = {
   def doTheDelete(node: Option[Node], parent: Option[Node]): Option[Node] = (node, parent) match {
      // Handle other possibilities of (node, parent)
      ...
      // Case where the root needs replacement
      case (Some(BranchNode(label, left, right)), None) => {
         // Root replacement.
         // Get the replacement node and it's parent
         var (replacement, repParent) = getTheLeastInTheTree(right)
         // Mark the previous parent of the replacement node as not having this child anymore
         if (repParent.get.label > replacement.get.label) {
            repParent // <-- This is where I am stuck
         }
         ...
   }
   ...
}
```

I have removed other functions from the above snippet to keep the code concise. Now, at "This is where I am stuck" how do I set the repParent's `left` or `right` nodes to `None`? I thought that declaring `left` and `right` as `var`s in the `case class` definition of `BranchNode` would allow me to mutate it?

Answer (score 1):

You can not mutate the `case class` because the idea behind the case class is to hold immutable data.

But what you can do is copy the data into newer one and change the value that you want.

```
  val leftNode = Option(LeafNode(2))
  val rightNode = Option(LeafNode(3))
  val root = BranchNode(1, leftNode, rightNode)

  //i'm deleting or Nonefying the right node in following example
  val newRoot = root.copy(right = None) //only overriding the right node
  assert(newRoot.label == 1)
  assert(newRoot.left == leftNode)
  assert(newRoot.right == None)
```

Comment: Thank you. How would you copy if the type of `root` were `Option[Node]` instead of `BranchNode`? Would we have to go through pattern matching the `root` with all three possibilities and copying?